# iPhone map application not respecting spn

Tags: iphone

I am passing a link on the iPhone with google map instructions:

http://maps.google.com/?q=Cabelas&mrt=loc&sll=30.444064,-97.813874&spn=0.006313,0.01133

In a browser, this works great, centering the map in my area and bringing up the store near us.  But on the iPhone, when the internal maps application intercepts the call, I get a view of the US, most of the params are being ignored.

Can anyone spot any reason for this, or have a reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [Apple URL scheme reference](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007894) for the rules for Maps links. Especially:

> All parameters must be supported.

Since the `mrt` parameter is not supported, I suspect that one is the problem.